# C# JSON.Net Iterate through Given JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am in a struggle, I am new at C#, I have read already many ways to retrieve a JSON string, but the one I have been given is not in any example, so please help.

This is the JSON I get:

```
{
"projects": {
    "0": {
        "projectId": "3",
        "title": "Project Title",
        "excerpt": "Far Far Away from somewhere it was a place where blah blah blah",
        "date": "11/04/2018"
    },
    "2": {
        "projectId": "17",
        "title": "New Project Title",
        "excerpt": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula....",
        "date": "25/06/2018"
    },
    "3": {
        "projectId": "18",
        "title": "Another Project Title",
        "excerpt": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo\n ligula eget...",
        "date": "06/07/2018"
    }
}
```

I have this class (not sure if it is ok)

```
public class PeopleProjects
{
    public List<string> Projects { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Excerpt { get; set; }
    public string PublishedDate { get; set; }

}
```

Should I use a loop like foreach? if so, how? also, please notice that each project is inside a dynamic number, which can be any number, it is really driving me crazy, please help

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to manually parse the JSON? Have you looked at JSON.NET? https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: As it is PeopleProjects will not work to deserialize your JSON.your class must respect the structure of the json and the names of the properties must be exact matches or you must use annotations for JSON.net to be able to do it's job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you should have:

```
public class ProjectCollection
{
    [JsonProperty("projects")]
    public Dictionary<string, Project> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    [JsonProperty("projectId")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("excerpt")]
    public string Excerpt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("date")]
    public DateTime PublishedDate { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use:

```
var collection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProjectCollection>(json);
foreach (var project in collection.Projects.Values)
{
    // Use project.Id etc
}
```

The `ProjectCollection` class corresponds to your "root" object - it expects a `projects` property in the JSON, and then treats each property within `projects` as an entry in the dictionary. In the `foreach` loop above I've ignored the key, but you could always use:

```
foreach (var pair in collection.Projects)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key}: {pair.Value.Id}");
}
```

That would print:

```
0: 3
1: 17
2: 18
```

with your sample data, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much it did the trick. I had to change a couple of things, in Excerpt [JsonProperty("date")] to [JsonProperty("excerpt")] and in date instead of DateTime I had to use String. So many thanks. Now in order for me (maybe others as well) to learn more, where can I find more info about the [JsonProperty()], no idea what it is and when to use it. Thanks again!!

Comment: @Jorge: Whoops, the JsonProperty was obviously a typo. You *should* be able to use `DateTime`, but you may need to configure Json.NET in terms of the format. (If you could change whatever produces the JSON to use ISO-8601, that would be a lot better!) I think it's worth experimenting a bit further on that - the earlier you can treat the publication date *as* a date rather than as a string, the better.